# About the 2016 Stack Overflow developer survey results

Tags: discussion, support, survey, survey-2016, terminology

As I was reading them, I saw the [developer-profile-programmers-engineers-and-developers](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-programmers-engineers-and-developers) and a big question arose to myself: When I take the survey myself next year, what I will declare to be? A **developer** or a **programmer**? As one can see from [my CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/), I am not much experienced with the terms!

From googling around I thought that the terms were equivalent. However, I asked an IBM intern and he told me that a developer is a more general role, while a programmer is something specialized.

I am really confused about the terms and about what I should declare in the survey?<sup>*</sup>

<sub>*If the terms get cleared up, I will then be able to identify myself, I guess :)</sub>

Comment: The point of the question in the survey is to find out how people *self-identify*.

Comment: @Oded yes, that's why I am asking. How I am going to identify myself if  I do not know which one to pick (since I am not aware of the *diff*)? Thus I am asking for help.

Comment: That's the point. It is entirely up to you. We can't help with how you think about these terms and how they related to each other (not that there is any common agreement on that - every company and every developer/programmer/software-engineer means something slightly different by them).

Comment: You can be many things at once!

Comment: Oh @Oded I see, that's also helping, thanks! Yes I can samthebrand, but that doesn't mean I am. :)

Comment: The people that still remember photographic film call themselves "programmer" :)

Comment: "software developer", "computer programmer" distinction between the two is blurred at the best of times. Admission: *I use both interchangeably all the time.*

Comment: I've always considered the term "programmer" to be a nicer way of saying "code monkey" (someone who is very good technically at coding, but perhaps can't see the 'big picture' of an application). In truth, however, I probably only think that because I perceive the term "developer" as somewhat fancier. As far as I'm aware, the terms are completely equivalent in most cases.

Comment: A developer [develops](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/develop) and a programmer [programs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program). In reality, though, there's usually no difference, so it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Anyone buying car insurance in the UK might be interested to learn that picking 'Software Engineer' from the (fixed) list of occupations [results in slightly lower premiums](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/insurance/car-insurance-job-picker/) than picking 'Computer Programmer'.

Comment: Thank you all, good comments. Would really like to see the downvoters justifying their votes :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whichever you want. Some people say that developers and programmers are the same thing, others think there are slight differences, still others think they're completely different things. Kinda similar to [this](https://xkcd.com/747/):

[image: XKCD 747: Geeks, nerds, and people with strong opinions on the distinction between the two]

Point being, there is no right or wrong answer here; the question is about what you yourself would call yourself.

Comment: Point taken βα!

Comment: Definitely a geek appreciate the xkcd ref!